# gdb segmentation fault line number missing with c++11 option

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, ns-3

I have compiled my ns3 project using c++11 option. However, when I run gdb with any of the executable to find the source of a segmentation fault, gdb does not print the line number and it only gives the name of the function in which the segmentation happened. Here is the output of gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff40aac5d in ns3::WifiInformationElement::DeserializeElementBody(ns3::Buffer::Iterator, unsigned char) ()
   from /home/hanyassasa/MyWorkSpace/source/ns3-80211ad/build/libns3.25-wifi-debug.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff40aac5d in ns3::WifiInformationElement::DeserializeElementBody(ns3::Buffer::Iterator, unsigned char) ()
   from /home/hanyassasa/MyWorkSpace/source/ns3-80211ad/build/libns3.25-wifi-debug.so
#1  0x00007ffff439d044 in ns3::MgtFrame::DeserializeInformationElements(ns3::Buffer::Iterator) ()
   from /home/hanyassasa/MyWorkSpace/source/ns3-80211ad/build/libns3.25-wifi-debug.so
#2  0x00007ffff4193420 in ns3::MgtAssocRequestHeader::Deserialize(ns3::Buffer::Iterator) ()
```

Is there any additional option I should add when I compile with c++11 so that gdb prints the line number of the error?

Comment: The usual `-g` option?

Comment: can you tell me the output of `file <file_name>` and `objdump -g libns3.25-wifi-debug.so`. Instead of pasting whole output just confirm whether debugging symbols present or not.